# Login with Facebook cannot do login 2nd time after logout

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

My case is,

- launch an app
- tap on login with facebook button
- The login with Facebook is done successfully.

Now,

- Do logout by click on the logout icon. (It redirect to login screen back)

After log out,

- Do tap on the Facebook button to re-login and nothing is happening.

While looking on Logcat, 
it shows

> E/LoginFragment: Cannot call LoginFragment with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.

Comment: Post your code for login into FB

Answer (score 0):

you have to be clear current facebook session data

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```